# AJAX return file created with php script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to implement excel export function for my table. I'm sending form data with ajax and php script creates file with this data and then nothing. I want ajax return the file created with php. Here is my code.

```
$('body').on('click', '#excel', function() {        
    var veri = $('form[method="get"]').serializeArray();
    veri['action'] = 'userexcel';
    jQuery.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: <?php echo '"' . admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) . '"';?>,
           data: veri,
           success: function(data){
               alert(data); 
           }
        });
    return false;
});
```

And my php function

```
function exportExcel($filename='ExportExcel',$columns=array(),$data=array(),$replaceDotCol=array()){
header('Content-Encoding: UTF-8');
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8'); 
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=".$filename.".xls");
echo "\xEF\xBB\xBF"; // UTF-8 BOM

$say=count($columns);

echo '<table border="1"><tr>';
foreach($columns as $v){
    echo '<th style="background-color:#FFA500">'.trim($v).'</th>';
}
echo '</tr>';

foreach($data as $val){
    echo '<tr>';
    for($i=0; $i < $say; $i++){

        if(in_array($i,$replaceDotCol)){
            echo '<td>'.str_replace('.',',',$val[$i]).'</td>';
        }else{
            echo '<td>'.$val[$i].'</td>';
        }
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
}
```

Comment: There's no need to use ajax for this. Sending proper headers for downloading will force you to stay on the same page.

Comment: This is a wordpress site so it is better to use wp's ajax functions for security reasons.

Comment: security reasons?? Either way it is a http request... lol

Comment: What are the reasons? Someone will find the uri?

Comment: Wordpress has "nonce" thing for requests and it is very powerful i think. I dont want to mess with securing my script while wordpress does most things for me. Like checking user logged in, privileges etc.

Comment: There're no nonces in your js-ajax code.

Comment: Because first i want to achieve my priority goal first. And then i will take care other things. Can we turn back to my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [excel](/questions/tagged/excel) generation code works just fine, however, if you want to force the browser to download that file, you have two options.

**Create a local [xls](/questions/tagged/xls) file**

You'll have to actually save that file somewhere on the server, then return the link to it and then initiate the download by changing the `window.location.href = "<url_of_xls_file>"` after the successful AJAX call.

**Make the form post directly to the [wordress](/questions/tagged/wordress) AJAX call**

Now, if you don't want to create an [xls](/questions/tagged/xls) file on the server, then you'll have to get rid of the [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax) approach, change your form `action` attribute to `admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )` and manually add the `<input type="hidden" name="action" value="userexcel">` [wordpress](/questions/tagged/wordpress) action inside your form.

You'll have the browser to popup the download dialog with both of these methods.